# Javascript MVC Deleting after space

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am working on a pretty simple MVC project.
I have a div that when clicked passes a string to a javascript function.

The javascript calls a partial view and fills out a bootstrap modal with it.

When the passed argument has a space in it, the space and everything after it is lost.
If no space is present everything works as expected.

I have tried replacing the space with '&nbsp;'

But either way has the same outcome.

The issue seems to be between javascript and the partial view call.

Passing 'myString' works fine and the partial view receives 'myString'

But when passing 'my String' the partial view receives 'my'

View Line:

```
<div onclick="myFunction('@item.PartNumber')">
```

Javascript:

```
function myFunction(pn){
    $('#myModal').load('/controller/pnDetails?partNumber=' + pn);
};
```

Partial View:

```
public ActionResult pnDetails(string partNumber)
{
   return PartialView(details(partNumber));
}
```

Comment: have you tried putting `@item.Partnumber` into a variable on your cshtml, then passing the variable in as a parameter in the click method?

Comment: I did and it had the same effect

Answer (score 1):

OK I got it.  Instead of `&nbsp;` I used `%20` and this worked.

Comment: Just a heads up, you can use `@Uri.EscapeUriString(item.PartNumber)` to do this in future.

Answer (score 0):

You might use HttpUtility.UrlEncode